# how to change spinner item right on the time when clicked a button in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner, and there are 10 items in the spinner. The texts from each item are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. I also have a Next button. Now I want that, each time I clicked to the button, the item in the spinner changed. Unfortunately I can not do that. Anybody have a solution for me?

Comment: please provide some code or some detail so i will help u.

Comment: Please post your code here.()

Comment: when on click changed **from what to what**?

Comment: thanks all. That was my mistake. When clicked on a button, we can use spinner.setSelection() to change the current item. I just have a bug in another line so this function did not work.

Comment: i just posted sample for you. its not the code which you copy and paste in your file. if this helped you, please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can take hint from the below code and can implement your requirement

```
 int i = 0;
    Spinner spineer = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner)
    Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button)
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    spinner.setSelection(i++);
                      if(i>=10) i =0;

                }
            });
```